# gcc not respecting my include directory order

Tags: gcc, include, gnu-make

I'm attempting to build some code using a temporary version of an include file in my local ../include/records directory.  The orignal lives in /home/apps/include/records.  I have my gcc command set to search ../include before /home/apps/include, but it's still picking up the original module from /home/apps/include and reporting errors.  If I rename the original in /home/apps/include, then gcc picks up my local edited copy and it compiles clean.  So, what's up with the include order...?  This 'local include first' logic has always worked for me in the past, but this may be the first time I've used it since migrating from AIX to Linux.

Is there something beyond the order of the -I command-line options that could be overriding the requested include order?

The source module include statment is:

```
#include "records/novarec.h"
```

and the gcc command line looks like this:

```
$make
gcc -DLINUX64 -c -g  -I. -I../include  -I/home/apps/include -I/home/apps/include/em -I/home/apps/include/odbc -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-implicit-int -Wno-format-security -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-discarded-qualifiers  novaget.c
```

The compiler complains about an undefined value that's in my local copy of novarec.h, but not in the production /home/apps/include/records/novarec.h:

```
novaget.c: In function ‘calcComscoreDemoV1’:
novaget.c:2651:15: error: ‘CSCD_W21_49’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘CSCD_W25_49’?
   fval = *(dm+CSCD_W21_49);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: There is nothing unique about how include files are handled on Linux.  You provided us with the full pathname to the original but nothing about the path to the local copy.  My suspicion is that the local copy is `../include/novarec.h` when it should be `../include/records/novarec.h`.  If it's the latter then look at file and directory permissions.  If none of that is helpful, you can add the `-v -E -dD` options to the compile line and look at what is going on.

Comment: The path to novarec is correct (../include/records/novarec.h)., but the -v -E -dD flags turned up something interesting:  It showed another include file in /home/apps/include also pulling in "records/novarec.h", and getting it from /home/apps/include/records.  So, is it possible that because gcc is pulling in file1.h from /home/apps/include that it uses that include path to pull in file2.h when file1.h includes it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the answer is this:

My module called in 2 include files.  The first one also includes the second one - and the first one lives in /home/apps/include.  That seems to make gcc search there for the second include file - even though /home/apps/include is not the first include directory in my path.

When I reverse the 2 include statements in my .c file, the correct path is followed for novarec.h.  i.e. when I code:

```
#include "spottvdemos.h"  (this modules has a #include "records/novarec.h")
#include "records/novarec.h"
```

novarec.h gets picked up from /home/apps/include, but when I code:

```
#include "records/novarec.h"
#include "spottvdemos.h"
```

novarec gets picked up from ../include, which is what I wanted.

Comment: Relative paths are always resolved relative to the file being parsed.  I recommend that instead of using `-I../include` you use something like `-I$(dir $(CURDIR))include` (if you're using GNU make) to get the fully-qualified path.

Comment: Interesting.  Even if the file being parsed is in a different directory than the file being compiled?   That seems unnecessarily confusing.  Though in the case of nested includes, there's a chance the author of the calling model wouldn't know about the nested onces and might not specify the necessary include path on the command line.  But still, how does it hurt to check the -I path list first before reverting to relative paths for nested files.  Oh well, at least now I know what to expect.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually in practice, ../include is the same as $HOME/include, which might be even more self-explanitory.

Comment: Yes, even in that case.  And the reason is as you mention: the person writing the file, whatever file it is, expects it to be that way and it would be very breaking if it weren't that way.  Your situation, where you're trying to replace a header that is in the global space, is actually unusual.  Usually you would expect the global header to find the global included file and the local header to find the local included file.

Comment: I personally would recommend against using `$HOME/include` because it's not relocatable: if you decide to move your project to some other directory it will break.

Comment: I'm not actually trying to 'replace' a global include file - I'm trying to work on it.  I.e. provide a temporary replacement, which will eventually be put into the standard production location.  Adding a local include path upfront always worked for me in AIX, but in linux it doesn't.  Including the file prior to including the production file that also wants to include it solves the temporary development problem.  i suppose, copying the other include file to my ../include directory might work too...

Comment: My suggestion was to use a fully-qualified path rather than a relative path.  But there are various ways to make this work.

Comment: I had an interesting argument over [there](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/407056/the-case-against-path-expressions-in-include-directives) @MadScientist